# A function that goes through a dictionary and prints out key names

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

The function needs to accept a dictionary, loop through it and print  out the keys and values.

`The format I would like it in is:
[keyname] => [value]
If the key contains another dictionary, the function could call itself and print it out in place? The effect I’m going for here is:
When it’s a single value:
[keyname] => [ single value ]
When it’s a nested dictionary
[keyname] => 
[keyname] => [Value]
[keyname] => [value]`

I am however unsure of a function that does this

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What language is this in, Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if it's a dictionary like this:

`If TypeName(Value) = "Dictionary" Then` ... ( call itself (Value) )